# Deserialize json arrays with newtonsoft

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

how can I deserialize json arrays with newtonsoft?

Here my json file:

```
{
    "one": [
      {
        "one":"1",
        "two":"2", 
        "three":"3"
      },
      {
        "one":"1",
        "two":"2", 
        "three":"3"
      }
    ],
    "two": [
      {
        "one":"1",
        "two":"2", 
        "three":"3"
      }
    ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
myList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<MyClass>>(jsonFile);

public class MyClass
{
    public string one{ get; set; }
    public string two { get; set; }
    public string three { get; set; }
}
```

Maybe I need change in some way my json file?

Comment: There's this fancy feature in Visual Studio under the "Special Paste" menu, that pastes the Json you have in your clipboard, into a C# file, and it will construct all the C# classes required to comply with said Json structure

Comment: If you have so simple json, just use this site http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class needs to match the structure your JSON. It should look like this:

```
public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public string One { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public string Two { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("three")]
    public string Three { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public List<Foo> One { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public List<Foo> Two { get; set; }
}
```

Now it will properly deserialize:

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json));
```

Comment: And what if the JSON adds a "forth" key? Should he need to add a Forth property then? This is wrong. Just deserialize it as a Dictionary<string, MyClass[]>.

Comment: @JOSEFtw If the OP had stated: *"I want to add keys dynamically without modifying my JSON"*, then perhaps a dictionary would be more suitable. Since the OP simply wants to deserialize the JSON into the proper structure (and "one", "two", "three" are probably not his keys anyway), this should do the job.

Comment: Sure, but if you had the same JSON, would you do it like you answered or with a Dictionary? I really hope that you answer "with a Dictionary"...

Comment: @JOSEFtw Again, If I needed to dynamically parse key value pairs which are unknown at compile time, the sensible way would be to either use a dictionary or even parse a `JObject`. I do not think this is the case here as the OP hasn't stated so.

Answer (score 0):

That is no JSON array, it is an object with two array properties.

Use http://json2csharp.com:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public string one { get; set; }
    public string two { get; set; }
    public string three { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<YourClass> one { get; set; }
    public List<YourClass> two { get; set; }
}
```

(Don't we *still* have a canonical question for this? Every day the same...)

Comment: Why add all this classes? Why not just Deserialize it as a ``Dictionary<string, MyClass[]>`` ?

Comment: @JOSEFtw what benefit does that offer? Granted, classes `One` and `Two` could be one (your `MyClass`), and the `RootObject` could contain two `List<MyClass>` instead. I'm more in favor of compile-time type safety (no need to do string matching).

Comment: Benefits? It's DYNAMIC, you don't need to add a new ``Class Forth``, ``Class Fifth`` if the JSON updates....

Comment: @JOSEFtw "dynamic" is a buzzword. The issue you mention is solved by my update. If the JSON changes, you need to change your code anyway. Then I'd rather regenerate the classes and have a compile-time error than forget to change a string and get runtime errors.

Comment: haha no? If he adds a "forth" : [] to his JSON, you would not need to change the code if you use a Dictionary? See my answer and try it yourself.

Comment: @JOSEFtw you do need to change your code if you want to actually access it. Sure, you can loop over the dictionary, but it'll have no semantic meaning. Without telling your code what "fourth" means, it can't do anything useful with it.

Comment: It really depends on what is the use of the json file. You two both have your valid points. Just saying here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your class structure you have to change your json file into this:

```
[
   {
      "one":"1",
      "two":"2",
      "three":"3"
   },
   {
      "one":"1",
      "two":"2",
      "three":"3"
   }
]
```

With this json file style the deserialization

```
myList= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <List<MyClass>>(jsonFile);
```

will complete properly.

Your above json file has two arrays in it. Because of that the deserialization will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
`public class Foo
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public string One { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public string Two { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("three")]
    public string Three { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("one")]
    public List<Foo> One { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("two")]
    public List<Foo> Two { get; set; }
}`
```

and to deserialize object use

```
` RootObject _rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>
  (jObject.ToString());`
```

Answer (score 0):

You should deserialize it as a `Dictionary<string, MyClass[]>`

```
var test = "{ \"one\": [ { \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":\"2\", \"three\":\"3\" }, { \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":\"2\", \"three\":\"3\" } ], \"two\": [ { \"one\":\"1\", \"two\":\"2\", \"three\":\"3\" } ] }";
var testar = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <Dictionary<string, MyClass[]>>(test);
```

This would work out of the box if there is more keys added like Forth, Fifth and so on.

[image]

Comment: And what happens if the actual change in the dynamic json is of `MyClass`, and not of the dictionary keys? Why not go out of your way and use `Dictionary<string, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`. Make this super generic.

Comment: I find it funny that you downvote my answer which has a proper (non dynamic) structure, yet your answer only supplies a half dynamic approach, where you don't even know if the OP really needs any of this.

Comment: It's "PROPER" in a HARDCODED way. But I will not argue with you, if you think that it's okey to add a Forth, Fifth and Sixth class when the JSON get's updated, then go ahead :)

Comment: The solution you're offering will have to be modified if any of the properties of `MyClass` update, and not the external key-values.

Comment: Yes of course, but it's way less code to change then creating a new Class for every KEY like Class One, Class Two, Class Three, Class Four... well well, I don't care, I just think thats better to use a dictionary ;)

Comment: Your "reasoning" has many hidden assumptions in them, in which the OP has stated absolutely none of them. But this is non the less a different, suitable approach. Don't try forcing a "one approach solution" just because you think it's better. I'd see that it's actually needed first.